# Send Attachment in Emails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the User should get CV instead of CVFilePath. I am able to get the CVFilePath as per it has been called. But unable to get the Resume doc. Can anyone help me how to get the CV to be sent on Button click.

Please see the code for your reference.

Button Click code:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uploadCV.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uploadCV.PostedFile.FileName);
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(uploadCV.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileName = fileName + "_" + Guid.NewGuid() + "." +      Path.GetExtension(uploadCV.PostedFile.FileName).TrimStart('.');
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ResumeUploadFolerPath), fileName);
        if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(ResumeUploadFolerPath)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(ResumeUploadFolerPath));
        }
        uploadCV.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
        applicant.CVFilePath = ResumeUploadFolerPath + "/" + fileName;
    }

    _careerHelper.Save(applicant);
    _presentation.SendApplicantEmail(applicant);
    _presentation.SendJobMail(applicant);
}
}
```

Code: Mail which is sent to the respective user:-

```
public void SendJobMail(Applicant applicant)
{
    StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    sbuilder.Append("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><body>");
    sbuilder.Append("<div>");
    sbuilder.Append("<p>An application for the job posting has been submitted</p>");
    sbuilder.Append("<table>");
    sbuilder.Append("<tr><td>Position</td><td>" + applicant.Job.Position + "</td></tr>");
    sbuilder.Append("<tr><td>Location</td><td>" + applicant.Job.Location + "</td></tr>");
    sbuilder.Append("<tr><td>Business Unit</td><td>" + applicant.Job.BusinessUnit + "</td></tr>");
    sbuilder.Append("<tr><td>Name</td><td>" + applicant.Firstname + " " + applicant.LastName + "</td></tr>");
    sbuilder.Append("<tr><td>Contact</td><td>" + applicant.ContactNumber + "</td></tr>");
    sbuilder.Append("<tr><td>Email</td><td>" + applicant.Email + "</td></tr>");
    sbuilder.Append("<tr><td>City</td><td>" + applicant.City + "</td></tr>");
    sbuilder.Append("</table>");
    sbuilder.Append("</div>");
    sbuilder.Append("</body></html>");

    MailMessage rblemail = new MailMessage();
    rblemail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"]);
    rblemail.To.Add(new MailAddress(applicant.Job.EmailId1));
    rblemail.To.Add(new MailAddress(applicant.Job.EmailId2));
    rblemail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    rblemail.Subject = "Job Acknowledgement : " + applicant.Job.Position + " - " + applicant.Job.Location;
    rblemail.Body = sbuilder.ToString();

    Common ObjCom = new Common();
    ObjCom.SendEMail(rblemail);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you're attaching the attachment to the MailMessage object.

You should be able to use the CVFilePath to attach the file to the email, as per this  [tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-email-attachment.htm)

Something like:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(applicant.CVFilePath));
rblemail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: Its giving me long error, some what like this: "An error occured please contact administratorCould not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\~\Uploads\CV\abc_cb2ab9e1-0980-475c-8f92-989451c0a9cd.pdf'."

Comment: You'll probably need to use the server.mappath function on the filepath (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx), edited code above.

Comment: its giving me Server does not exist in the current context.

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to reference the context to get the server instance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks DarkHippo, it worked :) Really Appreciated ur help.